# I am a citizen by state X, but I bought a house in state Y and then changed my citizenship from X to Z

Tags: real-estate

(all the instances of state here means a state in the general sense of a "country", not in the federal state of say a "[U.S.A. state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_date_of_admission_to_the_Union)").

Let's assume that I am a citizen by state **X**, but I bought a house in state **Y** (with the passport type for identification being that of state X) and then at some point I have changed my citizenship from that of state X to that of state **Z**.

How does the change of citizenship and the use of a new passport type may be used against me, in state Y?

- Someone tries to use the fact that I no longer use a passport issued by state X to say that I no longer owe the property (due to racism)
- Someone real estate official demanding ransom for changing all records from about passport type X to about passport type Z
- etc.

Comment: Why do you think that your change of citizenship will anyhow affect the ownership?

Comment: @Greendrake because of proving "identity", one can claim that I am not the owner (or no longer the owner) and maybe even conspire to use that to somehow get the apartment or at least disconnect me from ownership due to some odd reason such as racism.

Comment: Why do you think that your change of citizenship will affect your "identity"?

Comment: @Sneftel I don't think that at all, surly it won't, but someone might use that to try to claim that I can't own the apartment, that's what I am afraid about.

Comment: "_someone might use that to try to claim that I can't own the apartment_" — if anyone does that, let them claim that through the court (which they will lose), or just tell them where to go.

Comment: Jurisdiction(s) in question?  I'm assuming the nation is a federal one like the U.S. that uses "States" for the subnational regions (U.S., Germany, Mexico, Brazil, Australia, ect) but that's a stretch based on what's given.

Comment: @hszmv nope, it's a state in the general content of a "country".

Comment: Then you're going to have to specify the states of x, y, and z.

Comment: @hszmv why?... Why does it matter which is each one of the states? I want to get general information about what to do in such a case... I deliberately don't specify countries, if I have to specify the countries than I would prefer to consult a local lawyer than to ask a general question but I really want to ask a general international question. I will try to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general principle: you don't have to do anything.

While I can't rule out that *some* country might have a law that removes title to property from citizens of a certain other country (perhaps as part of some economic sanctions), this isn't generally the case.

Generally, your property belongs to you, not "you, a person who is only a citizen of X."

As for your examples...

> - Someone tries to use the fact that I no longer use a passport issued by state X to say that I no longer due owe the property (due to racism)

This isn't relevant.  Your passport has nothing to do with your property ownership.  My passport expired recently, but no one gets to come take my stuff.

> - Some real estate official demanding ransom for making changing all records from that of passport type X to those of passport type Z

Well...corrupt officials don't really need a legitimate excuse to extort bribes, but this seems like a particularly flimsy one for the same reasons as above.  They could probably also extort a ransom to process your property tax payment before the deadline, or some other completely made-up reason.

Comment: "While I can't rule out that some country might have a law that removes title to property from citizens of a certain other country" - I'll note that China's property laws make sharp distinction between residents and foreigners.   If a Chinese citizen were to renounce citizenship, it would probably change their rights in regards to any property in China.